# JVM: A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

I have a `tomcat` server which sporadically crashes. I have the following log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007fed94555ed0, pid=107977, tid=140617220847360
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_181) (build 1.7.0_181-mockbuild_2018_05_16_11_23-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.181-b00 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.14
# Distribution: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 Beta (Santiago), package rhel-2.6.14.10.el6-x86_64 u181-b00
# Problematic frame:
# v  ~StubRoutines::jbyte_disjoint_arraycopy
#
# Core dump written. Default location: //core or core.107977
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/jvm-107977/hs_error.log
```

I tried interpreting the coredump using `gdb`, but it doesn't seem to have the debugging symbols file.

Can anyone help as to what can be the possible issue?

Comment: `# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/jvm-107977/hs_error.log` maybe take a look at that?

Comment: There is insufficient information in your question to provide even a minimal diagnosis.  Look in the hs_error.log file, and if you need to dig deeper, the duplink explains how to debug a Java core file.  (Which has a different format to a conventional core dump.)

Comment: `SIGBUS` on x86(_64) Linux usually means something truly terrible happened. Use the latest JRE and do a hardware stress-test before bothering to investigate the core dump itself any further.